# ¿Como sumar días a una fecha y pasarle la suma a un inputdate en c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor

hola comunidad tengo un problema en un formulario dentro de una pagina de `blazor` tengo dos `inputdate` en el primero selecciono una fecha actual y a esa fecha le quiero `sumar 45 días` una vez sumado esos días pararle esa fecha a otro `inputdate` dentro del formulario, pero no se como realizar esto , anteriormente lo hice en `javascript` con `jquery` pero en este momento estoy trabajando con `blazor` y `c#` y se me esta complicando un poco.

estos son mis inputdate:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
    <label>Fecha de Cotización</label>
<InputDate class="form-control" @bind-Value="@cotizacion.FechaCotizacion"></InputDate>
<ValidationMessage For="@(() => cotizacion.FechaCotizacion)"></ValidationMessage>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
  <label>Fecha de Vencimiento</label>
<InputDate class="form-control" @bind-Value="@cotizacion.FechaVencimiento"></InputDate>
<ValidationMessage For="@(() => cotizacion.FechaVencimiento)"></ValidationMessage>
</div>
```

se que se puede hacer algo como esto pero la verdad no se por donde empezar:

```
nuevaFecha = nuevaFecha.AddDays(45);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como tienes enlazado FechaCotizacion podrias hacer que en el cambio de valor de la propiedad cambie el valor de la otra (sin desencadenar un evento y manejarlo)
Es util, pero deberias ver en que "momento" quieres enlazarlo.

Entonces, simplemente hacer que cada vez que se modifica el valor de la propiedad de la "Fecha 1" (en tu ejemplo FechaCotizacion) cambiar el valor de la "Fecha 2" (FechaVencimiento) y

Arme un ejemplo..., puedes probar en vivo y en directo aquí en blazorfiddle

- https://blazorfiddle.com/s/soykw9pn

Lo copio aqui a la parte del html y code

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Date 1</label>
        <input id="txtDate" type="date" required @bind-value="_date1" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Date 2</label>
        <input id="txtDate" type="date" required @bind-value="_date2" />
    </div>
 </form>
```

```
@code{
  private DateTime _date1Value;
   private DateTime _date1 { 
     get {
         return _date1Value;
     } 
     set{
         _date1Value = value;
         _date2 = _date1Value.AddDays(45);
     } 
} 

  private DateTime _date2 { get; set; }

  protected override void OnInitialized()
  {
      _date1 = DateTime.Now;
  }
```

}

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guía

Answer (score 1):

Una opcion es agregar tu operaciones de fecha dentro de `@{}` y enseguida asignarlos en tus controles de input.

Ejemplo:

```
@{
    var fechaActual=DateTime.Now;
    var nuevaFecha = fechaActual.AddDays(45);
}
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
  <label>Fecha de Vencimiento</label>
<InputDate class="form-control" @bind-Value="@nuevaFecha"></InputDate>
<ValidationMessage For="@(() => nuevaFecha)"></ValidationMessage>
</div>
```

otra opcion seria solo pasar la fecha inicial en tu formulario y en tu **Backend** realizar la operación para la nueva fecha.

En javascript

```
var newfecha = new Date($('#fechinicial').val());//otro formato new Date(año,mes,dia,hora);
var dias = 45; // Número de días a agregar
newfecha.setDate(newfecha.getDate() + dias);//asigno los dias a la fecha
console.log(newfecha.getDate() + "/" + (newfecha.getMonth() +1) + "/" + newfecha.getFullYear());
```

Comment: pero como seria si no quiero la fecha actual  var fechaActual=DateTime.Now; sino la fecha seleccionada en el primer input a esa sumarle los 45 días, cotizacion.FechaCotizacion.AddDays(45); no puedo agregarle AddDays no me aparece como opcion

Comment: Lo que necesitas entonces es un evento que se ejecute cuando selecciones la primera fecha